# Test a simple button component that has a prop(className) passed in and check if the className is present in the document? Jest/React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi I've got a simple ButtonComponent I want to test

```
const ButtonComponent = ({ label, iconName }) => (
    <Button>
        <Icon name={iconName} />
    </Button> 
);
```

iconName props is optional so I want to create a test that will check if iconName is passed in props
& if so is the Icon name present in the Component.

Below code is what I've tried but the test doesn't pass because `received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null`. I want to update the the testProps by adding in iconName and then test if it exist. I am newbie with testing - Many thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

const testProps = {
    label: 'test label'
}

test('action button renders with iconName props if passed', () => {
    const { rerender} = render(<ButtonComponent {...testProps} />);
    const updatedProps = testProps['iconName'] = 'test-icon-name-prop';
    rerender(<ButtonComponent {...updatedProps} />);
    expect(document.querySelector('.test-icon-name-prop')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was how I assigned new property to the object and the Icon tag prepend `.fa` classname. Below is the correct way.

```
 testProps.iconName = 'test-icon-name-prop';
 const updatedProps = testProps;
 rerender(<ButtonComponent {...updatedProps} />);
 expect(document.querySelector('.fa-test-icon-name-prop')).toBeInTheDocument();
```